# Can I use wordpress themes without wordpress?

Tags: themes, theme-twenty-twelve

I didn't find answer for my question so I'm decided to ask here, so:
Can I use wordpress themes (for example: Twenty Twelve) without using wordpress?
I really like this theme but I don't want to use wordpress.

**UPDATE**
I don't need a theme functionality, but only a layout, colors (everyghink what is visible, (html/css)) and I want to use this theme (of course with modified code) in my own application.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what do you exactly want to do. A WordPress theme is not only a look and feel, it is a whole stack of functionality. Functionality comes from WordPress core. What do you exactly want from a theme? Maybe we can help you more if you clarify further.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use wordpress. But that is all up to you. As stated in the answers, the simple answer is no, you can't use wordpress themes outside wordpress.

Answer (score 3):

/wp-content/themes/twenty-twelve/style.css

will have a lot of the visual elements of the theme in it to get inspiration, however you must realise that each of the elements coded into the css is designed to go with each one of the div or other elements designed in wordpress... Back coding it will almost be harder than writing it from scratch.

Also Wordpress is now an incredibly powerful tool with infinite customisation abilities. It's not just the blogging tool it used to be years ago. There's not much else out there that can achieve so much for the price (or lack of it) and have so many support channels for you to get to grips with it (ie WPSE!!)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for general HTML/CSS templates, not Wordpress themes.

As the name suggests, Wordpress themes are designed to be used with Wordpress only.

For general HTML/CSS templates, you could search Google for phrases such as:

"HTML CSS themes"
"HTML CSS templates"
"HTML CSS themes 2014"
etc.